# How to Fetch the data from Login page to My-Details Page in ionic 3

Tags: php, angular, typescript, ionic3

I have login page which is working fine. Once the customer logs into account account he will be redirected to "HomePage" now HomePage will have all the data of customer. Below is My loginPage.ts file code which is working fine:

```
    this.auth.login(this.loginCredentials).subscribe(data => {
         if(data){
             this.customerdata = data;
             if(this.customerdata['status_code'] == '200'){
                 this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage,{customerdata: this.customerdata});
             }else if(this.customerdata['status_code'] == '000'){
                 this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
             }
         }
     })
```

Problem is, I have one more page "MyDetailsPage.ts" I want above same data in this page also. I am moving to this page through SIDE-MENU section. So I cannot use PUSH function and send data.

So please help me out.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using NavParams and Events you can do that

Events is a publish-subscribe style event system for sending and responding to application-level events across your app.

NavParams are an object that exists on a page and can contain data for that particular view.

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

first page (publish an event when a user is created)
constructor(public events: Events) {}
createUser(user) {
 console.log('User created!')
 this.events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
 }
second page (listen for the user created event after function is called)
constructor(public events: Events) {
events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
  });
}
```

Refer link https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

Or try with params

```
 constructor(public navParams: NavParams){
  // userParams is an object we have in our nav-parameters
   this.customerdata=this.navParams.get('customerdata');
  }
```

Comment: No luck, it's not working. Do i need to use the 'publish' in my login.ts page ?

Comment: Try with navParams